# GlusterFS vs NFS vs SAN?

Tags: glusterfs

We have SAN storage and we are willing to go with GlusterFS beside it, is that possible
Can I use GlusterFS on top of SAN storage?
What is GlusterFS?
How it is different than NFS?

What are the use cases that force me to go with GlusterFS?